# How to link excel file to sql server 2008r2 management studio

Tags: excel, hyperlink, sql-server-2008-r2

we have recently adopted to sql server 2008r2 from access. We are completely new to it. We need to work on data which comes in excel spreadsheets. In access we directly link the data to it and run the queries. This similar approach is available in sql server also? If not how to link the excel files into sql server?
what is sql server compact?

Answer (score 0):

In order to link the excel files : In excel go to data tab. There you will find the From Other Sources option. A wizard will appear requesting the Server name and your credentials to the db -> next -> select the db you want to connect to and then the table and click finish.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "linking" your Excel workbook or sheets to SQLServer database. Are these always on the same host?

In any case, you can easily import your Excel data into a SQLServer table:

```
INSERT INTO sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YOUR_SQL_TABLENAME
SELECT EXCEL_COLUMN_NAME1 [, EXCEL_COLUMN_NAME2...] FROM
OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Data Source=C:\YOUR_EXCEL_FILENAME.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[Sheet1$]
```

This will import from Sheet1$, if you have named your worksheets, then use the name.

Comment: I have tried the code but it is showing error for OPENDATASOURCE.